# Dynamic plot in each iteration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

In the following code, `plot(plot_x,plot_y,'-k');` in current iteration shows the previous iterations plots.

But I want to show only the current iteration plot, i.e., previous plot should be disappeared. However, `plot(N_x,N_y,'Ob','MarkerSize',10);` should be there always. What kind of modification should I do?

```
N = 50;
L = 20;
itr = 5;
N_x = (rand(N,1)-0.5)*L;
N_y = (rand(N,1)-0.5)*L;
plot(N_x,N_y,'Ob','MarkerSize',10);
grid on;
hold on;
axis([-0.5*L 0.5*L -0.5*L 0.5*L]);
for n = 1:itr
    out = randperm(N,5);
    plot_x = N_x(out);
    plot_y = N_y(out);
    plot(plot_x,plot_y,'-k');
    hold on;
    pause(1);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plot loop, ask the `plot` function returnig the handle of the line, then, after the `pause` statement delete the line by calling the `delete` function.

```
for n = 1:itr
    out = randperm(N,5);
    plot_x = N_x(out);
    plot_y = N_y(out);
    %   
    % Get the handle of the line
    %
    hp=plot(plot_x,plot_y,'-k');
    hold on;
    pause(1);
    %   
    % Delete the line
    %
    delete(hp)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can update the `XData` and `YData` properties of a single line instead of creating a new one.

I've added comments to the below code to explain the edits

```
N = 50;
L = 20;
itr = 5;
N_x = (rand(N,1)-0.5)*L;
N_y = (rand(N,1)-0.5)*L;
plot(N_x,N_y,'Ob','MarkerSize',10);
grid on;
hold on;
axis([-0.5*L 0.5*L -0.5*L 0.5*L]);
p = plot(NaN, NaN, '-k'); % Create a dummy line to populate in the loop
for n = 1:itr
    out = randperm(N,5);
    plot_x = N_x(out);
    plot_y = N_y(out);
    set( p, 'XData', plot_x, 'YData', plot_y ); % Update the line data
    drawnow(); % flush the plot buffer to force graphics update
    pause(1);
end
```